# How to enable ScrollViewer for RibbonComboBox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, ribbon

Using the following code, the dropdown-list of fonts runs off the screen. Setting `ScrollViewer` does not show scrollbars as I expected. A secondary issue is that I can mouse-move in the dropdown, but not mouse-scroll with mousewheel.

```
<RibbonComboBox 
    xmlns:ComponentModel="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
    ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource FontTemplate}"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">

    <RibbonComboBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="myFonts" Source="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <ComponentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Source" />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
        <Style x:Key="FontStyle">
            <Setter Property="Control.FontFamily" Value="{Binding Source}" />
            <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="16" />
        </Style>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="FontTemplate">
            <StackPanel VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FontStyle}"
                   Text="{Binding Source}"
                   ToolTip="{Binding Source}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </RibbonComboBox.Resources>

    <RibbonComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource myFonts}"/>
    </RibbonComboBox.ItemsSource>

</RibbonComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: this seems to do what I want, more or less.

```
<RibbonComboBox xmlns:ComponentModel="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase">
    <RibbonComboBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="myFonts" Source="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <ComponentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Source" />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
        <Style x:Key="FontStyle">
            <Setter Property="Control.FontFamily" Value="{Binding Source}" />
            <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="16" />
        </Style>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="FontTemplate">
            <RibbonGalleryItem>
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FontStyle}"
                   Text="{Binding Source}"
                   ToolTip="{Binding Source}"/>
            </RibbonGalleryItem>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="myFontTemplate">
            <RibbonGalleryItem>
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FontStyle}"
                   Text="{Binding Source}"
                   ToolTip="{Binding Source}" />
            </RibbonGalleryItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </RibbonComboBox.Resources>
    <RibbonGallery Name="RibbonGallery" MaxColumnCount="1">
        <RibbonGalleryCategory ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myFonts}}"
                   ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource myFontTemplate}"
                   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                   ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
    </RibbonGallery>
</RibbonComboBox>
```

Comment: Using this code, the drop-down shows the fonts in their own style and I can scroll the list using the mouse. However, the selected item (aka after DropDownClosed) will retain the style, making it look awkward. Haven't figured out how to manipulate that.